# Award travel to Italy, separate return

Tags: italy, one-way

I'm American and I have enough miles on United to go from USA to Italy but not the return.

Can I book the one way flight and then a separate flight on a different carrier for return (actually my friend would book that because she'll be coming back with me as well.)

Is there any problem for visa or something to do doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't United allow you to partially pay for a round trip with points, and the rest with cash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beit on a single ticket or two, you would have a ticket to return home, so for entry into Italy, you fullfill the rule on having a *return/onwards ticket*.

Now, this is likely not a great deal, one-way flights are usually priced **way higher** than return, but that *may* depend on the situation.

Comment: Thanks! Well the one way from USA to Italy with UAL miles has good departure & arrival times and it's with money it's expensive, whereas any combination for the round trip with money is terrible and expensive.

Comment: You'll find the one-way return trip to be the expensive one. They are often more than the roundtrip. Check prices for the return trip before you commit.